# Forcing zero instead of NA in R

Tags: r

I have this function called `newBamAD` and dataframe `x`. what this function does is it matches the letters in REF and ALT columns and grabs the respective numbers for `REF` and `ALT` values in `x`. What I need to know is how do I make this function give 0 in ref or alt column instead of NA. How do I replace NA with zero here?

```
x <- as.matrix(read.csv(text="start,A,T,G,C,REF,ALT,TYPE 
chr20:5363934,95,29,14,59,C,T,snp
chr5:8529759,,,,,G,C,snp
chr14:9620689,65,49,41,96,T,G,snp
chr18:547375,94,1,51,67,G,C,snp
chr8:5952145,27,80,25,96,T,T,snp
chr14:8694382,68,94,26,30,A,A,snp
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,T,snp:2530921
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,G,snp:2530921
chr16:2530921,49,15,79,72,A,T,snp:2530921flat
chr16:2530331,9,2,,,A,T,snp:2530331
chr16:2530331,9,2,,,A,G,snp:2530331
chr16:2530331,9,2,,,A,T,snp:2530331flat
chr16:2533924,42,13,19,52,G,T,snp:flat
chr16:2543344,4,13,13,42,G,T,snp:2543344flat
chr16:2543344,42,23,13,42,G,A,snp:2543344
chr14:4214117,73,49,18,77,G,A,snp
chr4:7799768,36,28,1,16,C,A,snp
chr3:9141263,27,41,93,90,A,A,snp", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))





  newBamAD <- function (x,base.types=c("A","C","G","T")) {
      # the version above
      rownames(x) <- 1:nrow(x)
      ref <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'REF'])]
      alt <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x[, 'ALT'])]
      which.flat <- grep('flat$', x[, 'TYPE'])

      alt[which.flat] <-  sapply(which.flat, function (i,base.types) {
        sum(as.numeric(x[i, c( base.types[!( base.types %in% x[i, 'REF'])] )] ) ,na.rm=TRUE) },base.types)
      cbind(x[,c("start","REF","ALT","TYPE")],bam.AD=paste(ref, alt, sep=','))
      # cbind(x, bam.AD=paste(ref, alt, sep=','))
    }
```

Comment: Try `gsub(NA, 0, newBamAD(x)[,5])` .  Add another line in the function to do that

Comment: Get rid of that pesky `as.matrix` from around your data import. It will cause you more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @thelatemail If it was a dataframe, wouldn't there be NA's?

Comment: @MAPK - yep, but that's not really the issue. You have numeric and text variables in your dataset, a matrix can only store text OR numeric data. You're essentially coercing everything to the same type with `as.matrix`, which is not wise.

Comment: This is one of the same problem I described in your earlier post as matrix can hold only a single class

Comment: @RichardScriven tried that, but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to do that

```
 gsub('NA', 0, newBamAD(x)[,5])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take the advice of thelatemail and switch to data frame, then take the NA out first

```
df <- as.data.frame(x)
types <- c("A", "T", "G", "C")
df[types][is.na(df[types])] <- 0

head(newBamAD(df))
#               start REF ALT TYPE bam.AD
# 1     chr20:5363934   C   T  snp  59,29
# 2      chr5:8529759   G   C  snp   0, 0
# 3     chr14:9620689   T   G  snp  49,41
# 4      chr18:547375   G   C  snp  51,67
# 5      chr8:5952145   T   T  snp  80,80
# 6     chr14:8694382   A   A  snp  68,68
```

Comment: can we not put 'is.na'  within the function?

Comment: Sure you can.  You could make it the first line of the function.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone took my advice, I'd have... $4.

Comment: @RichardScriven Your solution doesn't work. In gives this error: `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @MAPK I think you have to create the `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` so that the columns will be 'character' .  In your example, wrapping with `as.matrix` created the problem as it converted the dataset columns to 'character` and when you reconvert it back, the columns are 'factor'.  so, Try `df <- read.csv(....)`

Comment: @MAPK - I'm near certain Richard is right. Start from scratch using `read.csv` and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` without `as.matrix` or any other changes. Trust me, I won't even ask for a dollar.

Comment: @thelatemail that is what I have used to read the file. I don't think it's just a dollar, I owe you more. Thank you for helping.